# AwsSamAutoDependencyLayerNestedStack is not being generated while using cicd deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, sam

My AwsSamAutoDependencyLayerNestedStack is not being generated while using cicd deployment with this code. However, if I run sam sync it works perfectly. Is there anything that's not accurate in this code?

I have pasted my data from cicd below. I do not see any error in my pipeline, its success. However, still its not being generated.

```
- sam build --parameter-overrides DeploymentPhase=staging DeploymentVersion=live --region ap-southeast-1
- sam deploy --parameter-overrides DeploymentPhase=staging DeploymentVersion=live --s3-bucket 1231-ap-southeast-1 --stack-name staging-live --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --no-fail-on-empty-changeset --no-confirm-changeset --region ap-southeast-1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. The `AwsSamAutoDependencyLayerNestedStack` is a helper stack only used during `sam sync`. It's not needed for regular deploys, thus it will not be created when running `sam deploy`  from a CI/CD pipeline.

See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/accelerating-serverless-development-with-aws-sam-accelerate/